# How to show popup menu on longpress?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How can I show a Custom Popup Page on user longpress? each option has to have a press event.

I saw few topics about this but they weren't helpfull.

this is my code:

```
for (int l = 1; l < ustkatmasasayisi; l++)
{
    var buttonustkat = new Button
    {
        Text = l.ToString(),
        HeightRequest = 45,
        WidthRequest = 45,
        Margin = 5,
        CornerRadius = 100,
    };
    buttonustkat.Clicked += ustkatbuton;
    ustkat.Children.Add(buttonustkat);
}
```

---

```
async void ustkatbuton(object o, EventArgs args)
{
    secilenmasa = buttonustkat.Text;
    secilenkonum = "Üst kat";
    await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new menu());
}
```

i have to set the longpress event on `buttonustkat`

Comment: your code sample doesn't seem correct, i did an edit, see if it makes sense

Comment: I did, your text was more correct grammarly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use **Custom Renderer**

#### in Forms

create a custom Button

```
using System;

using Xamarin.Forms;
namespace App13
{
    public class MyButton:Button
    {
        public  EventHandler LongPress { get; set; }
    }
}
```

#### in iOS

```
using System;

using UIKit;

using App13;
using App13.iOS;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyButton), typeof(MyButtonRenderer))]
namespace App13.iOS
{
    public class MyButtonRenderer:ButtonRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if(Control!=null)
            {
                var longPress = new UILongPressGestureRecognizer(()=> {

                    var myButton = Element as MyButton;
                    myButton.LongPress?.Invoke(myButton, new EventArgs());
                
                });

                Control.AddGestureRecognizer(longPress);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### in Android

```
using System;

using Android.Content;

using App13;
using App13.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(MyButton),typeof(MyButtonRenderer))]
namespace App13.Droid
{
    public class MyButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
    {
        public MyButtonRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if(Control!=null)
            {
                Control.LongClick += Control_LongClick;
            }
        }

        private void Control_LongClick(object sender, LongClickEventArgs e)
        {
            var mybutton = Element as MyButton;
            mybutton.LongPress?.Invoke(mybutton,new EventArgs());
        }
    }
}
```

Then you could handle the long press event

```
var buttonustkat = new MyButton
    {
        Text = l.ToString(),
        HeightRequest = 45,
        WidthRequest = 45,
        Margin = 5,
        CornerRadius = 100,
    };
buttonustkat..LongPress += Button_LongPress;
```

```
private void Button_LongPress(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            
}
```

Comment: Give this man a medal! You solved my 2 problems in same day :)